# Volume Level Meter using C#

Tags: c#, volume, microphone, naudio

I would like to ask if how to program a VOLUME LEVEL METER for STREAMING AUDIO. Using only the Laptop's stock Microphone i would like to know its sound level. Decibel(dB). Our project is to make a Volume Level Meter that would give us inputs for our true program which would get the decibels and would turn them into values.

Note:

Programming Knowledge: UNDERGRADUATE STUDENT
Compiler Used: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Operating System: Windows 7 Professional x64bit / Ultimate x64Bit

Comment: There is no question in your paragraph, just a work order. That is not the way things work here, mate. Please show us, that you have basic understanding of the work you are planning and don't expect others to implement a whole program for you.

Comment: what's this "our project"? Your project, maybe.

Comment: Sorry guys... Just desperate for answers. :(

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at [DirectSound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416960.aspx) which can be used to [capture waveforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416968.aspx). That will give you samples in (usually at least) 16 bit [resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth) (96Db *dynamics*).  The biggest difference in max/min over these values over a certain period (say, 1/60th of a second) will be the volume of that frame. The 'scale' goes from -32768 (lowest amplitude) to 32767 (highest amplitude).

If you "draw" these values in a bar representing the volume every frame you would get the "bouncing volume bar" you're looking for.

The *actual* Decibels you're looking for can only be determined if you calibrate the max. volume to a known # Decibels. This is because of input gain, quality of the microphone and many other variables that, in the end, only tell the ("form of the") "waveform". The max/min amplitudes measured do not correspond to a specific Decibels value of (say) 50 or 120.